# M1.9.x - Trying to get custom attribute in Navigation.php / Menu Creation

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am trying to get the `page_title` (custom category attribute) in **Navigation.php** (menu build up) to use as the html title attribute.

For example this is were we would use the extra attribute in an html ahref title attribute: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.3.x/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php#L308

We added this code, but it is not retrieving the page_title custom attribute

```
        $page_title = $this->escapeHtml($category->getPageTitle());
        if (empty($page_title)) {
            $page_title = $this->escapeHtml($category->getName());
        }
```

But `$category->getPageTitle()` is not returning anything

`$category->getPageTitle()`:
 How can we get the `page_title` attribute directly?

Answer (score 0):

The category collection doesn't load all attributes of a category by default. That would be a performance issue as well as loading each category separately in the navigation loop.

I think the best way to get a custom attribute of a category for using it in the navigation is to overwrite the category ressource model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category` and add your custom attribute  to the the fields returned by the collection in `getChildrenCategories($category)` method:

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
    $collection = $this->_getChildrenCategoriesBase($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('page_title')
        ->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested ... but it shoud work to add custom attributes here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.3.x/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml#L776-L784

```
    <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <name/>
                <url_key/>
                <is_active/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
```

(put it into own module of course ;) )

Comment: Thx! I fixed it adding the data as below "addAttributeToSelect" in getChildrenCategories ... but would this solution have the same result?

Comment: @snh_nl yes, it should have the same result. As said, i've not tested it. Can you give it a try?